# Remove duplicate parents if Child has specific value

Tags: javascript

I have the follow list:

[image]

In red are duplicates. Essentially I need to remove these duplicates and ONLY if the value is "Rate Inclusive".

Here's the DOM structure:
[image]

I've manage to create a simple loop as follows:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar__list-item'), i;
for (i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
  ...
}
```

But from here I'm having difficulties at writing the code to delete parents if `.sidebar__list-right` has value = "Rate Inclusive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Map` type to check if you already have an element with that name and if you have it, check whether the second value is `Rate Inclusive` or not. Something like this:

```
  let list = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar__list-item');
  let map = new Map();

  for (let i = 0, maxi = list.length; i < maxi; i += 1) {
    let name = list[i].children[0].textContent; // get the name
    let value = list[i].children[1].textContent; //get the value

    if ( map.has( name.toLowerCase() ) ) { //if you have it already...
      if ( value.trim() === 'Rate Inclusive' ) { //and is Rate inclusive...
        list[i].remove();
      }
    } else {
      map.set( name.toLowerCase(), true ); // If you don't have, add it. The value is set to true, but it doesn't matter.
    }
  }
```

You can also use a `Set` to perform the task.

https://codepen.io/isaacvr/pen/NWpyvPO

Comment: Great, it perfectly works. Thanks a million for your swift reply. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only problem I see is that .textContent returns "Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined". Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: If the html follows the structure you've shown, that error shouldn't happen. Maybe you're in a situation that needs to be handled in another way. Please make sure of that and if it's that te case, edit the question and mention me again and I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks, the HTML follows the above structure. When I try your code in developer console, I get the error, but the script gets executed anyway.
But if I try to implement the script in the source code or via Tag Manager it doens't get executed and just have the error message "Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined"

Comment: @AlessandroCrotti Check the codepen example please.